# Is it possible to use Jenkins' Maven plugin with non-Java build projects?

Tags: build, maven, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I have a list of Jenkins jobs that are independent, but it would be convenient if I could group them together to have them all run with the click of one button.  Each of the projects is concerned with deployment, not compilation.

I've found the bulk-builder plugin, but to use bulk-builder it's necessary to specify a pattern each time you wish to invoke it.

I'm looking for a Jenkins plugin that will allow me to group projects together, and the Maven system seems to suggest this is possible: I'd make a top level build job that sets up dependencies on each of the jobs I wish to run, then I'd just need to run my top level job.

**If possible, has anyone found Maven to be useful in managing dependencies of anything but Java?  Would I be able to use it in the way I'm expecting?**

EDIT:  These are all .net projects

Comment: What kind of projects do you use? C++, Perl, PHP, Ruby ?

Comment: edited to clarify they are .net projects.  But seeing as these are deployment projects using Nant, I didnt see the significance at first.

Comment: As far as i know there exist nmaven (http://incubator.apache.org/nmaven/) for .net projects ...so may be it's worth to take a look at that. And what about Ivy in relationship with nant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jenkins, you can explicitly define other projects to build upon a successful build (search for downstream). This way, you can have one project trigger bunch of others effectively grouping them.

Maven is a great tool but I wouldn't use it for this purpose.